# LINQ filter Datatable by n Columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I have made this class to retrive parts of an datatable like a pagination, everything works fine but the problem is that the method can only filter by one column, I have no ideia hwo to archive this using LINQ. I wanted to pass n columns  and n expression to be filtered.

example: 
column: Name, expression 'jonh'
column: city, expression 'florida'

here is my class:

```
public class Paging
{
    public enum Operator
    {
        Equal,
        Like
    }

    public static DataTable Page(DataTable dataTableToPage, int pageSize, int pageNumber, string columnToFilter, string expression, out int totalrecords, Operator Operator)
    {
        int skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;


        IEnumerable<DataRow> query = null;

        if (Operator == Operator.Equal)
        {
            query = (from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()
                     where dr[columnToFilter].ToString() == expression
                     select dr);
        }
        else if(Operator == Operator.Like)
        {
            query = (from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()
                     where dr[columnToFilter].ToString().IndexOf(expression, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                     select dr);
        }

        var queryConverted = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);

        if (queryConverted.Count() > 0)
        {
            totalrecords = query.Count();

            return queryConverted.CopyToDataTable();

        }

        totalrecords = 0;

        return new DataTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parameters `columnFilter` and `expression` and instead pass your data in a collection of `columnsFilter` and `expression`. You can create a custom class or just use a list of 
`Tuple<string,string>` like this:

```
public static DataTable Page(DataTable dataTableToPage, int pageSize, int pageNumber, 
    IList<Tuple<string, string>> columnToExpression,
    out int totalrecords, Operator Operator)
```

To create the Tuple you are doing something like this:

```
var colsExps = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
colsExps.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Name", "John"));
colsExps.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("City", "Miami"));
```

Then modify the code in your queries to something like this:

```
if (Operator == Operator.Equal)     
{     
    query = (from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()     
                 select dr);     
    foreach (var pair in columnToExpression)
    {
       string columnFilter = pair.Item1;
       string expression = pair.Item2;
       query = query.Where (dr => dr[columnFilter].ToString() == expresion);
    }    
}     
else if(Operator == Operator.Like)     
{     
    query = (from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()     
                 select dr);     
    foreach (var pair in columnToExpression)
    {
       string columnFilter = pair.Item1;
       string expression = pair.Item2;
       query = query.Where (dr => dr[columnToFilter].ToString().IndexOf(expression,
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }    
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
query = (from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()     
             select dr);     

// I'm not sure exactly what T you should be using in the following statement:
// DataRow should be the type of dr
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<DataRow>(); 

foreach (var pair in columnToExpression)
{
   string columnFilter = pair.Item1;
   string expression = pair.Item2;
   predicate = predicate.Or(dr => dr[columnFilter].ToString() == expresion);
}    

query = query.Where(predicate.Compile());
```

Since I haven't test this, I wonder if you need to do `dataTableToPage.AsQueryable()` instead of `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: Creating a class with properties for columnName, filterValue, and operator is probably best

Comment: @brad I think your solution work, but it does not work for me as I wanted to, I think I missed a point on my question... but anyway with your solution, Is like using an 'AND' ont he where clause, if I wanted to get a result using 'OR' that would not be possible. but tkx anyway +1

Comment: @rpmlins, I've added some info on `PredicateBuilder` which should help you do your OR comparisons.

Comment: well sadly I cant use `dataTableToPage.AsQueryable()` and I am receiving an error because of it :(

Comment: okey just got the solution `query = query.Where(predicate.Compile());` Thank you very much @Brad

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't query your DataTable in a class or method where you want to do pagination. That's breaking the responsibility of the class. You should rather separate those two behavior.

You can do it like that:

```
public static class Paging
{
    public static DataTable Page(this IEnumerable<DataRow> dataTableQuery, int pageSize, int pageNumber, out int totalrecords)
    {
        int skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;

        var queryConverted = dataTableQuery.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);

        if (queryConverted.Count() > 0)
        {
            totalrecords = query.Count();

            return queryConverted.CopyToDataTable();
        }
        totalrecords = 0;

        return new DataTable();
    }
}
```

Now that code is only caring about paging.

And for the query:

```
public static class DataTableQuery
{
    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> Where(this DataTable dataTable, string columnName, string expression) {
        return from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()
                     where dr[columnToFilter].ToString() == expression
                     select dr;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataRow> Like(this DataTable dataTable, string columnName, string expression) {
        return from dr in dataTableToPage.AsEnumerable()
                     where dr[columnToFilter].ToString().IndexOf(expression, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
                     select dr;
    }
}
```

I did them as Extension methods because in this case you are just extending that class behavior and they read nicely.

And you can use the code by doing:

```
int totalRecords = 0;
DataTable dataTable = ...;
var page = dataTable.Where("Name", "Jhon").Page(1, 1, out totalRecords);
var page = dataTable.Like("City", "florida").Page(2, 3, out totalRecords);
```

Comment: thank you for the advice @Adauto!! since my rep is too low, I cant vote up! but thx a lot

Comment: No problem! I just want to be aware that separating the concerns, you can add as many "filters" as you like and the paging will still work the same way because you didn't change it. I hope you see the advantages of that and I hope you like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need some sort of parser/walker to transform your string expressions into linq expressions. Once you have that you 'll be able to apply those filters.
You need something like a tiny linq provider. At least that's the only way to come to my mind...